# jQuery .load() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm generating table rows "N" times. If the user clicks "add row" buttons, I'm adding rows in the table.

So, I need to load one external file in one TD. How can I load an external page by class and not ID?

For example

```
$('.classname').load('ajax/help.html');
```

Comment: Not really sure what you want, but your code is correct. It will load the contents of `'ajax/help.html'` in every element with class `classname`. If this is not what you want, you have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate the td, you should have a reference (or be able to get one) and either load the file then. If you want to load the file later, give each td a generated, unique ID and then link a button or whatever to that td. If your scenario is different, amend your question and ill update my answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. my questions in that i want to load one external page in many place. so shall i use class instead of id? like $('.classname').load('ajax/help.html');

Comment: @user566373: Yes. IDs have to be unique, so you can only address **one** element with an ID. If you want to select multiple, the easiest way is to use a class.